# How to reseed identity column in database using localDB(MDF) in visual studio

Tags: c#, vb.net

My question is common, but how about reseeding nonsequential numbers of ID in LocalDB(MDF) in visual Studio, I have got a result in MS access to create Query is showing on Visual Studio server explorer on Stored Procedures then call by C# routine flow.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A primary key and an identity are two different things. A single column can be one, the other, neither or both. If you want to insert your own primary key values then you generally should not be making that column an identity in the first place. If you just need to disable the identity temporarily then you can turn `IDENTITY_INSERT` on and off as required using SQL code.